# Wordpress - Get custom fields from custom post types

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm a newbie and I'm creating an homepage where there are 4 blocks from this loop:

```
    <?php $query = new WP_Query( [
    'post_type'      => 'cases',
    'nopaging'       => false,
    'posts_per_page' => '4',
] ); ?>

<?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="roundedframe">
                <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
                    <div id="case-study-box" style="background-image: url('<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>');" class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
                        <a class="portfolio-box " href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                            <div class="portfolio-box-caption">
                                <div class="portfolio-box-caption-content">
                                    <div><img src="<?php echo $slideCentralImage['url']; ?>"></div>
                                        <div class="project-name">
                                        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="portfolio-excpert">
                                         <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Each block is a portfolio item which has many custom fields created with Advanced Custom Fields.
What I need is to get and display them on hover like a "caption".
Actually only the_title and the_permalinkg are working, but I don't know how to get the logo and the excerpt of them.

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `get_field('<field_name>')` to return or `the_field('<field_name>')` to print the values. You can read more here - https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/displaying-custom-field-values-in-your-theme/.

Just add like this `<div><img src="<?php the_field('slide_central_image'); ?>"></div>`, where `slide_central_image` is your image field name. Don't forgot to change 'Return Value' to 'Image URL'.

[image]

Comment: Just tried. It works. I found that but I dindnt understand how to do it. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think he can really explain it more simple than this - you are not getting your values. `<?php echo get_field('whateverField');?>` would echo out your acf field with name "whateverField".

Comment: You're amazing guys, thank you. It was like getting taken by hand! I'm so afraid of php :D. Many thanks, have a great day!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `<?php echo get_field('whateverField');?>` and do not forget to change return value image URL.